# Python: bytearray object becomes bytes (immutable) when populated

Tags: python, arrays, byte, mutability

I'm trying to read the raw contents of a binary file, so they can be manipulated in memory.  As far as I understand, `bytes()` objects are immutable, while `bytearray()` objects are mutable, so I read the file into a bytearray and then try to modify the latter:

```python
raw_data = bytearray()

try:
    with open(input_file, "rb") as f:
         raw_data = f.read()
except IOError:
    print('Error opening', input_file)

raw_data[0] = 55   # attempt to modify the first byte
```

However this last line results in a `TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment`.
Wait... *what* 'bytes' object?

Let's look into the actual data types reported by Python, before and after the array is populated:

```python
raw_data = bytearray()
print('Before:', type(raw_data))

try:
    with open(input_file, "rb") as f:
         raw_data = f.read()
except IOError:
    print('Error opening', input_file)

print('After: ', type(raw_data))
```

Output:

```
Before: <class 'bytearray'>
After:  <class 'bytes'>
```

So what's going on here?  Why is the type modified, and can I prevent it?

I can always create another bytearray object from the contents of `raw_data`, but it'd be nice if I could save memory and just modify the original in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the type modified? Look at the following:

```
>>> x = 12
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> x = 7.0
>>> type(x)
<class 'float'>
```

Sure, I assigned a value of 12 to `x` and as a result `x` had type *int*. But then I assigned a *new* value of 7.0 to `x` and that changed the type of value that `x` had. This is fundamental *Python dynamic typing* being demonstrated.

So it doesn't matter that you initially assigned a *bytearray* instance to `raw_data`. What counts is the *last* assignment to `raw_data`, which was:

```
raw_data = f.read()
```

And the call to `f.read()` returns class *bytes*.

The way you get around this is by pre-allocating a *bytearray* with the correct size and using `readinto`:

```py
with open(input_file, mode="rb") as f:
    # Seek to end of file and return offset from beginning:
    file_size = f.seek(0, 2)
    # Seek back to beginning:
    f.seek(0, 0)
    # Pre-alllocate bytearray:
    raw_data = bytearray(file_size)
    f.readinto(raw_data)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick exactly.  I'm still fairly new to the Python typing system so that's good to keep in mind.